# AucTeX (in Emacs) doesn't seem to find certain packages

Tags: packages, pdftex, emacs, auctex

I am using `AucTeX` in `emacs v23` in `PFD-mode`. When invoking the `pdflatex` compiler through `C-c C-c LaTeX` I get a `[...] file <some_package>.sty not found` error for some particular packages. For example, consider the following `foo.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Some advanced stuff here.}
  \begin{algorithmic}
    \Function{Increment}{$x$}
    \State \Call{Return}{$x+1$}
    \EndFunction
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Compiling the file using AucTeX (`C-c C-c LaTeX`) yields:

```
ERROR: LaTeX Error: File `algpseudocode.sty' not found.
```

However, if I invoke `pdflatex foo.tex` via the terminal, everything works alright.

The only packages I have so far experienced this behavior with are `algpseudocode` and `fmtcount`, included in the Linux packages `texlive-science` and `texlive-latex-extra`, respectively. The packages are, apparently, there; for example, I get the following in the terminal:

```
$ locate -b fmtcount.sty
/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/fmtcount/fmtcount.sty
$ dpkg -l | grep texlive-latex-extra
ii  texlive-latex-extra      2009-10ubuntu1           TeX Live: LaTeX  supplementary packages
ii  texlive-latex-extra-doc  2009-10ubuntu1           TeX Live: Documentation files for texlive-latex-extra
```

What I find particularly confusing is that I get no such error for package `footmisc`, which is also part of `texlive-latex-extra`.

(Please bear in mind that I do not have root access in the machine I'm experiencing this problem at. If it is needed, I can ask the administrators to do the fix - once I know what that might be - but I doubt they'd be willing to start attempting various approaches to it.)

---

**Update**

```
$ kpsewhich algpseudocode.sty
/auto/pkg/texlive-2009/texmf-dist/tex/latex/algorithmicx/algpseudocode.sty
```

It appears that the problem is caused by the `pdflatex` program invoked by AucTeX. As I mentioned above, if I run `pdflatex foo.tex` manually through the terminal, it works, and the first line of `foo.log` is:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009) (format=pdflatex 2010.6.1)  15 FEB 2012 17:15
```

If, on the other hand, I invoke the compiler through `C-c C-c LaTeX` in AucTex, the `foo.log` file is as follows (notice the difference between the TeX distributions seen in the first line):

```
This is pdfeTeX, Version 3.141592-1.21a-2.2 (Web2C 7.5.4) (format=pdflatex 2011.4.5)  15 FEB 2012 13:24
entering extended mode
**\input foo.tex
(./foo.tex (/auto/pkg/tetex-3.0/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2004/02/16 v1.4f Standard LaTeX document class
(/auto/pkg/tetex-3.0/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2004/02/16 v1.4f Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/auto/pkg/tetex-3.0/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/algorithms/algorithm.sty
Package: algorithm 

Document Style `algorithm' - floating environment
(/auto/pkg/tetex-3.0/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty
Package: float 2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
\c@float@type=\count87
\float@exts=\toks14
\float@box=\box26
\@float@everytoks=\toks15
\@floatcapt=\box27
)
(/auto/pkg/tetex-3.0/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
\@float@every@algorithm=\toks16
\c@algorithm=\count88
)

! LaTeX Error: File `algpseudocode.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.5 ^^M

*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 346 strings out of 94499
 4143 string characters out of 1173445
 49441 words of memory out of 1000000
 3593 multiletter control sequences out of 10000+50000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 500000 for 2000
 580 hyphenation exceptions out of 1000
 23i,0n,17p,157b,36s stack positions out of 1500i,500n,5000p,200000b,5000s
PDF statistics:
 0 PDF objects out of 300000
 0 named destinations out of 131072
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 65536
No pages of output.
```

I'm afraid I can't figure out how to point AucTeX to the *correct* `pdflatex` installation, though.

In case it's useful, I have the following AucTeX-related lines in my `.emacs` file:

```lisp
(setq TeX-auto-save t)
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
(setq-default TeX-master nil)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (TeX-fold-mode 1)))
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'visual-line-mode)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'LaTeX-math-mode)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'TeX-PDF-mode)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-reftex)
(setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX t)
```

Comment: Could it be that Emacs is picking up a different latex installation? Auctex just calls pdflatex or whatever and so missing package messages are likely to be from pdflatex, not auctex.

Comment: We could do to see the `.log` file you get. Also, what does `kpsewhich algpseudocode.sty` give?

Comment: Indeed, it seems that AucTeX uses a "different" `pdflatex` installation than the one in the Linux `$PATH`. I've updated my question to reflect this new knowledge, as well as the information you requested. Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing the following: You have two latex dists, as already mentioned. But only set the new one in say `.bashrc` and then start `Emacs` from a menu. Thus Emacs never see the `PATH` changes. Solution, try starting emacs from the command line so see if this helps (which then verify my theory), if this is the case perhaps a change to the overall system environment might be in order. I cannot see from your post which OS you are using. In Ubuntu it usually helps to mess with /etc/environment. Just remember to log out and in again when testing.

Comment: In emacs `M-x getenv RET PATH RET` will show the search path Emacs uses I think.   You could change the path in the `.emacs` or in the `.bashrc`(preferable) and see whether emacs picks it up.  And it might be a good idea to set the the TEX* vars in the startup files on the shell you're using

Comment: You were right guys, the problem was indeed caused by my starting Emacs from the Gnome panel (I'm on Ubuntu 11.04) which resulted in Emacs not getting the path I set in `.bashrc`. I cannot mess with `/etc/environment` for lack of root access, but I can get Emacs to use my `.bashrc`-set `PATH` by putting `(setenv “PATH” (shell-command-to-string “bash -i -c ‘echo -n $PATH’”))` in my `.emacs` file. I'll put that in my question text as well.

Comment: We'd like to keep answers separate from questions, so you should write a separate answer instead of editing your answer into the question. Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.

Comment: @sweeters then ask the persons with sudo access to make the correct changes.

Comment: @Sweeters: It shouldn’t be necessary to edit `/etc/environment`. Adjust the `PATH` in `~/.profile` and restart the X server. `~/.profile` is sourced during text as well as graphical login. Note that, in general, it is not a good idea to set environment variables such as `PATH` in `~/.bashrc`. Use `~/.profile` for this purpose.

Comment: @lockstep: That's a good point. I re-organized my question and solution as per your suggestion.

@daleif: Now that I know the correct changes, that would indeed by a way to deal with it. For it not to be a one-time patch, though, the administrator would have to do something similar to sourcing my `bash` `PATH`, so that it gets automatically updated, right?

@mhp: I tried setting my desired `PATH` in `~/.profile`, and invoking Emacs from the Gnome panel works. However, the terminal does not see the updated `PATH`, and if I try to `ssh` into this machine I see yet another `PATH`.

Comment: @Sweeters: Check the system `PATH` exported in `/etc/profile` or `/etc/environment`, prepend the directories you additionally need to the system `PATH` in `~/.profile`, ensure that neither `~/.bash_profile` nor `~/.bash_login` exist, ensure that the `PATH` is not modified either in `/etc/bash.bashrc` or `~/.bashrc`, and, finally restart the display manager. Then the resulting PATH should be independent of the login mode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was being caused by invoking Emacs through the Gnome panel, which results in Emacs being oblivious of the `PATH` as it is set through `.bashrc`.

A way to fix this is to have Emacs set its `PATH` to be the one seen by `bash`, by putting the following in the `.emacs` file (credit to Shane in [here](http://procrastiblog.com/2007/07/09/changing-your-path-in-emacs-compilation-mode/)):

```lisp
(setenv “PATH” (shell-command-to-string “bash -i -c ‘echo -n $PATH’”))
```

Comment: Undoubtedly, this is a working fix. But the actual problem is that the `PATH` is set in `~/.bashrc` (the initialization script for *non-login interactive* Bash), which means that applications such as Emacs might see a different environment, depending on whether they are invoked from a text or graphical terminal.

Comment: Indeed you are right, mhp; and I would generally prefer the solution you posted above. The problem I have with avoiding setting the `PATH` through `.bashrc` is that there is a "central" `.bashrc` file that's being sourced for all workstations in the network and I can only add my own customizations on top of that. Of course, I could ask that I self-administer my workstation, and then make sure that such customizations are set in the proper, so to speak, places, but then that might create a series of other complications I'd rather not deal with at the time.