# Beamer .sty files not recognized in Auctex emacs

Tags: beamer, emacs, auctex

I'm trying to create a `beamer` presentation through Auctex in emacs. In the process I have to include several style packages (`subfigure.sty`, `stmaryrd.sty`) in the `tex` file. However the problem is that when I try to compile the `.tex` file through Auctex, it throws me an error saying these style files are not available. However I do have a TeXLive installed in my computer and I'm able to compile the same file using TeXworks.

So the question is how can I make sure that the Auctex can read the style files that are installed in my system (I use Ubuntu 11.10 and the TeXLive is installed in `/usr/share/texmf-texlive/`).

Comment: check if you have 'kpsewhich subfigure.sty' installed. relevant http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44668/auctex-in-emacs-doesnt-seem-to-find-certain-packages

Comment: @texenthusiast Thank you for the thread suggestion. However I have the tex path suggested in my bashrc. For example the PATH variable is defined as `PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/i386-linux:$PATH`. All the executables (latex,kpsewhich) are all installed in the above mentioned directory

Comment: @RamBalachandran, I use [TeXmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/) all time, so i may not be best person to answer, [check this good place for more info](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50827/a-simpletons-guide-to-tex-workflow-with-emacs)

Comment: Are you using Mac OS X?  If so `PATH`, and other environment variables, don't get picked up by GUI applications like Emacs when you set them in `.bashrc`.  There are many questions on Stack Overflow about how to work around this.