# Auctex not finding package

Tags: emacs, auctex

This question is the same as [a previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44668/auctex-in-emacs-doesnt-seem-to-find-certain-packages?newreg=6dd756d6efd54805a6a0e886d48479ab), although I'm using emacs24. On attempting to compile a latex document, after starting emacs from ubuntu's launcher, the file, or the terminal, I get the error that `authblk.sty` cannot be found. The solution posted in the previous answer is to modify the .emacs file with

`(setenv “PATH” (shell-command-to-string “bash -i -c ‘echo -n $PATH’”))`

When I do this and start emacs, I get the error,

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading
`/home/usrname/.emacs':

Symbol's value as variable is void: “PATH”
```

What does this mean, and how do I fix it?

EDIT

Unlike the original question, `pdflatex foo.tex` also does not compile the document, because it too does not find `authblk.sty`. So I guess the problem is more basically in `pdflatex`?

Comment: @noname - What is the result when you type `tlmgr info preprint` in your shell?

Comment: The original error message turns out to only have been superficially similar. The actual problem was that emacs does not find and load packages during the compilation process, which is what I was expecting coming from Windows. A full install of `texlive-full` fixed the problem.

Comment: Emacs only questions are off topic.